# pycharm: pass console variables to script

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm running a script which loads some huge amount of data using pickles.
For this big amount of data, running the script takes a lot of time which in turn makes it very hard to work with (especially to debug).

For solving the problem above I thought about passing some of the variables defined in the console to the script. This will allow me to load the pickles only one time and just pass it to the script every time I want to use their data.

I tried to find a way to do this but couldn't find any.
Is there any way of doing passing console variables to a script?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I can just create a function in the script and then call it from the console instead of having `__main__`.
For example, for a script A.py, add a function b(params) and then in the console just run

```
from <pathToA>.A import *
b(params)
```